# Not able access link from pdf from Android Mobile

Tags: java, android, iphone

I have anhor tag in pdf.Link is clickable from web browser from windows system but Link is not clickable from android mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reader "software" ( of pdf file ) is responsable for rendering the anchor and catching the on click event. You can have in Windows too a plain pdf, without anchor, but you are using acrobat reader, or whatever. The reader on the android can / should do the same, you can have it your implementation to have the anchors and catch the on click on anchor and launch an intent.